# Entity Framework - Multiple Database Connections

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, poco

I have used Entity Framework code first with good results.

The project uses a second, legacy database which is already designed and running.

I'd like to call both databases in the project. Does any one have any suggestions of the best solution to do this?

I have done both seperatly (in tutorials) but never both. Yes its not the best idea to connect to two databases but each database has distinctly different datasets.

I am already using EF Code first and have been using POCO classes. Would you suggest creating a EDMX file as well? Assume would need two db context files?

Comment: Both databases have the same schema?

Comment: No they are entirely different schemes & different table names

Comment: If you just need to view certain data in the legacy db, consider using a view. If you need updates, you could reverse engineer the tables you need access to into code first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done several solutions where there was a Code First connection and a Database First connection used in the same project without any issues.  I would do as you stated, just create the edmx for the existing database.

I generally create one library project for *each* database and reference them from the main app project, just to help keep things from getting mixed up.

You just instantiate a context for each database and use them just as you would with a single context.  They act as completely separate, independent repositories.

Comment: Great yes that's what I needed. Keeping them separate in libraries is a way to separate concerns and functionality. Having them in one project seemed a messy way of doing it, thanks